# How to change layout of blocks in homepage?

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to figure out a way to change the layout of different blocks on my homepage.

Primarily this is what I want to do

Move the featured slider & new arrivals sliders up, ie right below the main slider.

I am a newbie to Magento. I have enabled template hints on my [site](http://www.singhcycle.com). I am not sure from where I should start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the cms page that uses as home page via System -> Configuration page:
[image]

Next, you can find the information regarding the page via Cms -> Pages page:
[image]

You can find the page by title as well as I have done on the screenshots.

So the information that you are interesting in placed into the Content section:
[image]

Also, it may be placed in the Design section as layout updates:

[image]

If you provide me more information about that section of your home page I can help you do solve this task completely.

Comment: Thanks! I got an idea from where I need to start! Thanks again